# VS Code Extension From Colt Steele Video for MySQL

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code

[Colt Steele MySQL Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJhF2.jpg) First time posting here. I was learning SQL when I came across Colt Steele's Video about Views and watching the video, I also learned that you can use VS Code for SQL. Now at the start of his video, he shows us his current set-up of his VS Code SQL and I am intrigued to know what extension is he (he did mentioned he used an extension for that) using to make the SQL script above and the results down below and I think this is more convenient than the default left I currently have.

Comment: what if you search for `SQL` in the Marketplace